# Meaning of phrase「その足を縫われたいか」

Tags: translation

I've been reading a Visual Novel and I couldn't understand what exactly「その足を縫われたいか」means. The only translation I could guess is -

> "You want that(your) leg(s) to be sewed?"

However I'm not really sure that it's correct here. So, here is some context, because the dialogue by itself is not really helpful.

Context: In the world of this VN exist lots of 人外(yeah and of course they are eating humans.). Main character (僕) is able to absorb their power by killing them. But if 人外's power is strong, in order to fully control it, as Ignis says, he must submiss it be his own will or to satisfy 人外's dying wish. In this case the dying wish was to kill Ignis. That's why she made 僕 a drunked and allowed the 人外 to control 僕's body, then they fighted and Ignis falsified her own death, because he wasn't able to submiss it with his own will.

> イグニス:「あぁ。素面のまま、襲いかかられると危ないからな」
>
> 僕が酔っていたから、イグニスも、軽くあしらえたという訳か。
>
> 僕:「ずいぶん手間を掛けるな。この前は、あの子に勝っていたじゃないか？」
>
> イグニス:「その足を縫われたいか？」
>
> 僕は首を振る。
>
> イグニス:「生身で獣と戦うのは骨が折れるんだ。布石を打たせてもらった」
>
> イグニスはベンチに座った。僕も、となりに座る。
>
> イグニス:「狼の力を使いこなすには、二つ方法がある。一つは、意志の力で屈服させる。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「その[足]{あし}を[縫]{ぬ}われたいか？」

means what it literally says.

"Do you want your leg(s) to get sewed up?"

What it is saying is "Do you want to get hurt in the legs so badly that you will need to have the cuts sewed up?"

Comment: Thank you very much, I would like to clarify one more thing, does she mean it as a threat, "If you won't shut your mouth now I'll hurt you?" Or talking about the fight before?

Comment: It would be a warning or threat.